# count merged cells and send a single mail to the users in different cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel, where in column B has email IDs, and in column D some subject is mentioned to send an email. For few records n column D, there are 2 or more email ids mentioned in different rows, and the data in column D is merged for all the records in column B. I want to send a single mail to all the email IDs for each subject from column D.

I tried with following code, but its sending different mail to each id, and taking the subject only for the first line, and for the remaining lines, for which the data is merged, its displaying the subject as blank.

```
row_cnt = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row

For k = 2 To row_cnt

 Set myApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set myItem = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
       subj = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & k).Value
       to_pers = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & k).Value

        ' If subj = 0 Then
          'subj = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F" & k - 1).Value
         'End If

    With myItem
        .Subject = subj
        .To = to_pers
        .HTMLBody = "Hello"
        .Display
        '.send
    End With
   End If

Next k
```

[image]

Comment: Start by moving `Set myApp = ...` outside the loop.

Comment: But it will just send one mail. There are multiple records in the subject column, with multiple maild ids linked to each subject.

Comment: I did not uderstand pretty good. Can you post an image of how your data looks like? Just change your data for fake names/emails, but I did not understand the "merged" cells part blank subject.

Comment: Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can base your strategy on the fact that in a block of merged cells only the top (left) cell can have any value, all the others are empty. So I would go this way:

```
 For k = 2 To row_cnt
    if cells(k,4)<>vbnullstring then subj = cells(k,4)
    to_pers = cells(k,2)
    ' send mail here
    irow=irow+1
next
```